# RVM looking for wrong path when installing

Tags: rvm

Asking RVM to

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3p551
```

fails because of `error fetching the ruby interpreter`.  earlier errors state

```
The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p551.tar.bz2'
```

and two fallbacks fails as well...

Checking the URLs, they effectively do not exist.

```
http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/
```

has the list of rubies, and a proper path to download is

```
http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.bz2
```

why is that dot directory in the middle of an otherwise proper path and how can I get RVM to get the right path (or use the archive downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rvm list known
```

to get the list of ruby versions.

I think that you can get this version by

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551
```

Comment: extra dot !  rather:  dash missing... before the 'p' edition!